# How to reflect process on before_update?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a project in which when I try to update some attribute, a long and exhausting before_update function runs. This function runs some scripts, and when they're finished successfully the attribute is changed.

The problem is that I want a way to reflect to current status of the currently  running scripts (to display some sort of 2/5...3/5... process), but I can't figure out a solution. I tried saving the last running command in the DB, but because the scripts are running in a before_update scope the commit is done only after all script are finished.

Is there any elegant solution to this kind of problem?

Comment: We use background jobs for that. E.g. the [que](https://github.com/chanks/que) gem. Split up the different parts in jobs, each job starts the next. A background job could update a progress indicator?

Comment: FWIW, running a long and exhaustive method in a `before_update` callback seems like an anti-pattern, IMO. I like the proposal from @nathanvda, do this asynchronously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you should avoid running expensive, cross-cutting code in callbacks.  A time will come when you want to update one of those records without running that code, and then you'll start adding flags to determine when that callback should run, and all sorts of other nastiness.  Also, if the record is being updated during a request, the expensive callback code will slow the whole request down, and potentially time out and/or block other visitors from accessing your application.

The way to architect this would be to create the record first (perhaps with a flag/state that tells the rest of your app that the update hasn't been "processed" yet - meaning that related code currently in your callback hasn't run yet).  Then, you'd enqueue a background job that does whatever is in your callback.  If you are using Sidekiq, you can use the [sidekiq-status](https://github.com/utgarda/sidekiq-status) gem to update the job's status as it's running.

You'd then add a controller/action that checks up on the job's status and returns it in JSON, and some JS that pings that action every few seconds to check up on the status of the job and update your interface accordingly.

Even if you didn't want to update your users on the status of the job, a background job would probably still be in order here - especially if that code is very expensive, or involves third-party API calls.  If not, it likely belongs in the controller, and you could run it all in a transaction.  But if you need to update your users on the status of that work, a background job is the way to go.